# How to validate on update mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this Schema :

It's update without validate . Where is my wrong . Please help me

Answer (score 2):

many solutions of this issue
A.do same thing in two step.

1. Find the result using findOne() method.
2. Add fields and save document using Model.save().

B. use pre update hook

```
Schema.pre('update', function(next) {
// ps: pre-reserve this good practices 
var self = this;
// self refer to calling model. you got self.first_name with modified value, also allow self.modelMethod 
// apply validation and go next      
  next();
});
```

C. Mongoose 4.0 Update

As noted in the comments and victorkohl's answer, Mongoose now support the validation of the fields of $set and $unset operators when you include the runValidators: true option in the update call.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Code looks fine, but try removing `$set` operator. It's already enabled by default when updating Model.

Also you are updating Array, that can cause some trouble. Try using [markModified](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_embedded_EmbeddedDocument.markModified) flag.

Comment: Well, I can suggest you to try running validators from Document-side. This should work in 100% cases.

Comment: Can you post this code ? I'm not sure about that . Here is code I tried `ContactSchema.path('first_name.0.value').validate(function...)` . But It not work correctly when I validate multifield

Comment: I'm talking about
`ContactSchema.findById(req.body.id).exec().then(doc=>{
    doc.first_name[0].value = req.body.first_name;
    doc.markModified('first_name');
    return doc.save();
})`

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose validation fails sometimes if you have inserted some entries before validation that do not follow validation rules.  After removing those entries mongoose validation still do not work.

I will recommend you to just drop your database and then try it again. It helps me most of the times.